# Indexes on FK columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a base table with 40 foreign key columns and 50 other columns containing various measures. Recognizing that FK columns should be indexed, should I really create 40 indexes on those 40 FK columns?

Comment: This question is lacking information.. Usually, yes, foreign keys should be indexed. Do your 40 foreign keys need indexes? Maybe.

Comment: The question for me is why in the world do you have 40 foreign keys in a single table??? This sounds like something went very wrong in the design phase.

Comment: If rows are deleted from the other tables, SQL Server would need to table scan to validate the row is okay to delete. If this is something that never happens, or if your table is never large, then you can get away without the indexes. This is almost always not the case though.